# Create table with id dynamically by template in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I want to assign Id of table data field which create dynamically.

My html code is:

```
{% for e in entries %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" id="tab" value="{{ e.child_name }}" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value='{{ e.dob }}' style="width:120px;" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="{{ e.school_name }}" class="form-control" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="{{ e.school_regno }}" style="width:100px;" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
        <select  class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:90px;" min="1995" value="1995" max="2050" placeholder="પ્રથમ ભરપાઈ લીધેલ વર્ષ">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="ચૂકવેલી રકમ">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How to set here unique id and name of all field which generate dynamically?

Comment: Are you trying to store info from a form into a table? Where is your views? Where is your django form? Where is your html form?

Comment: No i want to assign id and name to input field for store it in database,is this any possible way to assign unique id and name to all field of all rows?